# Pausar loop de um gif

Tags: r, ggplot2

Olá! Pessoal, estou com um problema em parar um GIF gerado com a função animate. Como servirá para uma apresentação de PPT, gostaria que o GIF ficasse parado no último dado para que os comentários pudessem ser feitos. Meu código no momento está assim:

```
animate(graf, 200, fps = 35, duration = 30, width = 650, height = 420, renderer = gifski_renderer( loop = F))

anim_save("rank.gif", animation = last_animation(), path = wd)
```

Adicionalmente, gostaria de pedir dicas para melhorar a fluidez e resolução dos gráficos.

O GIF pode ser consultado [aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQTnR.jpg)

Comment: Já tentou usar o argumento `loop=FALSE`?

Comment: Já, sim. Talvez eu não tenha me expressado bem quando fiz o post. Consegui, depois de alguns ajustes, parar o loop. No entanto, o meu loop congela no primeiro dado e eu queria que fosse no último.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adiciona `wrap = FALSE` a animação do ggplot. Por exemplo

```
transition_states(gear, transition_length = 2, state_length = 1,wrap = FALSE)
```